# Get type of device, means CDMA or GSM

Tags: android, gsm, telephonymanager, cellular-network, cdma

I am making an app in which I have to get device type. Which means is the device GSM or CDMA? And how do I get the manufacturer of the phone? Can anyone help me how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Look at [`TelephonyManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) for the CDMA vs GSM thing. And call `getPhoneType()`

And look at [The Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MANUFACTURER) regarding the manufacturer thing.

You can also try searching:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+get+manufacturer
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+check+network+type